# Google Cloud Run: Error: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created an API with https://www.starlette.io/, docker image `python:3.7-slim-stretch` and everything is running fine locally as well as when deployed on AWS ECS.

But when I try to deploy the same application on Google Cloud Run I can't get any request back.
I can reach the server with the browser on the root domain `/` but when I try to get access to `/prediction-url` I get response errors like `Error: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer` or `Service unavailable`. Tried to access the API with Insomnia, javascript request as well as curl requests.
Strange is, that everything works 100% on AWS ECS but I couldn't get it working on Googl Cloud Run.
Is there anything specific to take into consideration when deploying to Google Cloud Run?

The request route definition:

```
@app.route("/classify-url", methods=["GET"])
@requires("authenticated")
async def classify_url(request):
    img_bytes = await get_bytes(request.query_params["url"])
    return await predict_image_from_bytes(img_bytes)
```

The server start command:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "serve" in sys.argv:
        # int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
        uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, log_level="info")
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git python3-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80
ENV LISTEN_PORT=8080

# Start the server
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w 1", "-k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "-b 0.0.0.0:8080", "-t 8", "main:app"]
```

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the [known issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket), Cloud Run fully managed doen't support HTTP streaming. The team is working on it, but not available for now and no release date announced.

You can use Cloud Run on GKE if you want to use streaming, but the management and the cost aren't the same.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I've changed the ```timeout``` of ```gunicorn``` to something like
```CMD ["gunicorn", "-w 1", "-k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "-b 0.0.0.0:8080", "-t 30", "main:app"]```
and now it works. So I guess that error was more related to the timeout or response issue then a connection or socket problem.
Would still be interested how one could figure this out using the logs or better where and what logs to lock for?

Comment: @BenWhite - Review the changes you made and if you should use workers. Cloud Run does support background threads, but when the HTTP request returns, the CPU is idled to zero which means background threads will be CPU starved causing them to fail.

Comment: @JohnHanley this is a very interesting point I've actually never thought of. I think I got your point in the way that with workers the increase of the timeout rather prevents the thread CPU starving then the right setup between request <processing> response.
Could you please elaborate a little bit more on that or point me in the right direction where I could find more informations on the right setup.
For example, I know that an individual request takes about 3 sec to get processed, so how would I figure out what the right setup might be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BenWhite - Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response design. This means that processing starts when you call the endpoint and ends when the endpoint returns. If you have a complicated design (multi-threading) or long processing, Cloud Run might not be a good match. I do not recommend Cloud Run for tasks that call other services such as image recognition. Cloud Run should be a service, not a broker of other services. When you factor in your 30 second timeout and pricing, an F1-micro instance might be a cheaper and better choice.